# Measuring a custom element on a different website through google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for some advice in a best-practice sense. Let me sketch the situation:

There are 8 companies with similar services. Together they have decided to launch a new brand, which will encompass all of them. To promote this new brand, an ad will be placed on all of their websites. This add will include a CTA, and a close button which will minimize it into a bar. This element will be opened the first time someone visits the website. Upon later visits, element will be closed and only the bar (with a fold-out option) will be shown.

The CTA will link to a page in the site of the main brand.

I'm unsure on the best way to measure this in Google Analytics. The 8 sub-companies each have their own tracking, but integrating with theirs will take too much time for now.

My idea was to add separate tracking to the ad, firing a virtual pageview to the GA of the main brand's website, and tracking clicks on the CTA and closing/opening of the ad through events. To prevent interference with the GTM of websites it is placed upon, this would be hardcoded. To prevent interference with the current analytics (since it is a short-term campaign), I would measure this in a separate view, perhaps adding a custom dimension and excluding the hits with a filter.

This will give us insight in how often it is shown for the first time, how often it is opened/closed and how much people click through. Furthermore this will allow us to track a conversion rate on the landing page (which has a form to fill out).

The 8 websites on which it will be shown each have their own analytics, implemented in various ways (GTM, Classic Analytics or Universal Analytics). We do not wish to interfere with this.

Do any of you have tips/tricks or feedback on my plan?

Comment: Your plan is good. Try it and don't forget to rename your ga and set a name for your tracker.